# What does "vel potius" mean in this sentence from LLpsI?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

> Mare et ventī nēminī oboediunt nisi Neptūnō. Ille cūrāvit ut nōs ē tempestāte servārēmur nēve mergerēmur — ***vel potius*** nōs ipsī quī mercēs ējēcimus.

It's a sentence out of Chap.28 of *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata*.
It's the first time that ***potius*** has ever occured in this book but without any hints.

***Potius*** seems to be something like *rather* but I can't understand why there is a noun phrase (*we who throw the goods away*) and I can hardly figure out the meaning of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're basically there. *Potius* does mean "rather", so the whole sentence means:

> He made sure that we should be saved from the storm and not drown -- or rather we ourselves (made sure of it), who threw the goods away (=overboard).